# Finding the charge on a capacitor plate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, charge, capacitance, batteries

In a question, the left plate of a capacitor carried a charge Q while the switch was off;

[image]

When the switch is closed and the current stops flowing again, you're supposed to find the final charge on the right plate.

It's apparently done this way(say the electric field $= E$ ) ;

$$E = E_1 + E_2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

$$E = \frac{Q+x}{2A\epsilon_0}+\frac{x}{2A\epsilon_0} $$

Here, $V$ 's the potential, $A$ 's the surface area of the plates, and $d$ 's the distance between capacitor plates;

$$ V = Ed \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

$$ V = \frac{(Q+2x)d}{2A\epsilon_0}$$
Now,$$ C = \frac{\epsilon_0A}{D} $$ Now solving this;

$$x = CE - \frac{Q}{2}$$

But the final potential across the capacitor is always equal to the cell potential $\epsilon$, so why can't it be done this way?

$$\frac{Q + x}{C} - \frac{-x}{C} = E \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

$$Q+x+x = CE$$

$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -x \ =\frac{Q-CE}{2}$$

Comment: I think the charge on right most plate should be $\frac{Q}{2} - CE$, you forgot that it would have $-x$ charge

Comment: Yeah, I'll add the thing about the negative, but how is it Q/2 - CE and not (Q-CE)/2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can write the potential of a single plate as $\frac{\text{charge}}{\text{capacitance}}$ because how would you define the capacitance of a single plate?